# using arctan to find the angle of a sloped line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When finding the angle of a sloped line using $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$, when do you need to add $\pi$ to find the angle counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that **by definition** if $\theta = \arctan \left( \tfrac{y}{x} \right)$, then $\tan \theta = \tfrac{y}{x}$ and
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
So, the terminal ray of your angle points into the 1st or 4th quadrants (*i.e.* where $x > 0$).  Thus, if $x <0$, then your terminal ray is the 2nd or 3rd quadrants and your angle is off by half of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when $x$ is negative (and $y$ is positive) if you think the principal value of arctangent is in $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

If $x$ is negative and $y$ is negative, it is common to subtract $\pi$.

Read about the [`atan2` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Answer (score 0):

Typically whenever either $x$ or $y$ is negative.  Using $atan2$ is helpful because it does the checks for you regarding the possible combinations of negatives.